# Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} (f(x))^n dx$ exists if and only if $\mu ( \{x \in [0,1]: f(x)>1 \})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to solve this problem, but I have not succeeded. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance. The problem is:

Let $f$ be nonnegative measurable function on $[0,1]$. Prove that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} (f(x))^n dx$  exists if and only if $\mu ( \{x \in [0,1]: f(x)>1 \})=0$.

Comment: Try it with some function where that _isn't_ true, like $f(x) = 1.01x$, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: let be $G = \{x\in[0,1]\,:\, f(x) > 1\}$, $G_\epsilon = \{x\in[0,1]\,:\, f(x) > 1+\epsilon\}$.

Case $\mu(G) > 0$: this implies $\mu(G_\epsilon) > 0$ for some $\epsilon > 0$; use that $f\ge(1+\epsilon)\chi_{G_\epsilon}$.

Case $\mu(G) = 0$: this implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(f(x))^n$ exists for almost all $x\in[0,1]$; apply the [...] convergence theorem.